# Visual Studio 2012 won't deploy my SharePoint 2013 Workflow in an App

Tags: sharepoint, visual-studio-2012, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-workflow, sharepoint-apps

I want to add a SharePoint 2013 Workflow to my App (Web). It is a List Workflow. Workflow Manager and Service Bus are installed.

When I create a Workflow and want to debug/deploy the App, the Workflow is not listed as Workflow in the List.
("There are no SharePoint 2013 Workflows associated with this list")

I don't know why, I don't know if its a development or a server configuration issue.

Has someone had the same problem, but solved it?

(Everything is programmed in Visual Studio 2012. Lists, and Workflows, too)

Thank you,
Loki

Comment: Hi, I have exactly the same issue - workflows added to the SharePoint 2013 app project are not appearing on app web (any workflows - list, site). I am using on premise installation. Maybe it only works for SharePoint online?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue - to fix it you need to install SharePoint 2013 SP1. After doing it run following ps script on your server (see [this](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/Updates-For-SP2013-Workflow) post for details):

```
$WmsSap = Get-SPWorkflowServiceApplicationProxy
$WmsSap.RegisterWorkflowLifecycleManagementEnvironment()
```

Comment: I tried this.. it dint work... I have a SP 2013 workflow that does a simple writeTiHistory. It was developed via VS 2012. I have followed all the installation steps mentioned above.

Comment: Did you run configuration wizard after installing SP1?

Comment: @Yevgeniy.Chernobrivets - Config was run after the SP1.. Office dev tool is up to date.

Comment: @Yevgeniy.Chernobrivets Ok a fault from my side i think I have installed the March 2013 CU and thought that was the SP1... This is my current version number - 15.0.4420.1017 and now Im downloading KB2880552. Am on the correct direction?

Comment: I guess so. My current version is 15.0.4571.1502. As it states here (http://blogs.technet.com/b/steve_chen/archive/2013/03/26/3561010.aspx) if you have SP1 your build number should be at least 15.0.4569.1000.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59724/discussion-between-muhammedh-and-yevgeniy-chernobrivets).